# PHP Session Start Opens File Instead of Data Base Connection

Tags: php, mysql, session, oauth

After wrestling with it for days, I just noticed that the path in the below error message looks very odd.

open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_fvc591eu71mbrc4tabgtr83pg7, O_RDWR) failed:

Two things strike me as odd.

1. The destination appears to be a directory under /var/lib/php/, which seems like a very odd place for a script to create output files.
2. The script is supposed to be storing its session data in a MySQL data base.

Following is a condensed stack trace.

```
1/1) ErrorException
session_start(): 
open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_fvc591eu71mbrc4tabgtr83pg7,
 O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

in Session.php (line 40)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'session_start(): 
open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_fvc591eu71mbrc4tabgtr83pg7,
O_RDWR) 
failed: No such file or directory (2)', 
'/var/www/praesidium/pch/vendor/
lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Storage/Session.php',
40, array('startSession' => true,
'sessionVariableName' => 'lusitanian-oauth-token',
'stateVariableName' => 'lusitanian-oauth-state'))
at session_start()

in Session.php (line 40)
at Session->__construct()

in OAuth.php (line 101)
at OAuth->createStorageInstance('\\OAuth\\Common\\Storage\\Session')

in OAuth.php (line 132)
at OAuth->consumer('Salesforce')

in Facade.php (line 221)
at Facade::__callStatic('consumer', array('Salesforce'))

in PCHPageController.php (line 130)
        $oSFOAuthService    = \OAuth::consumer ( 'Salesforce' );                
at OAuth::consumer('Salesforce')
in PCHPageController.php (line 130)
at PCHPageController->ShowPageLogin()
at call_user_func_array(array(
   object(PCHPageController), 'ShowPageLogin'), array())
in Controller.php (line 55)
```

Following are key items from the environment array, taken from a local XDebug session.

```
$_ENV                       Array [24]
    [DB_CONNECTION]         "mysql"
    [SESSION_DRIVER]        "database"
    [DB_CONNECTION]         "mysql"
```

The application is using the LARAVEL 5 framework over PHP 5.6.32, running in Amazon Linux instance, and the session is being managed by the LUSITANIAN OAUTH module for LARAVEL , which I suspect is ignoring the session settings in the environment.

Following is my entire Session configuration file.

```
return [

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env ( 'SESSION_DRIVER' , 'database' ) ,

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => 'mysql',

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
| cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
| correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
|
*/

'store' => null,

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),

/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

];
```

All hailing frequencies are wide open.

Comment: can you provide the .env file content, i think you are saving the session to file

Comment: Thank you very kindly for your prompt reply. I have a one-line .env: APP_ENV=local, and I am following up on a suggestion from my client to substitute use \OAuth\Common\Storage\SymfonySession as Session for use \OAuth\Common\Storage\Session.

Comment: I see a note from @RiggsFolly that says that you edited the message. Off hand, I can't tell what you changed, and I would like very much to know what you changed, and to what end. Please advise at your convenience.

Comment: Minor formatting change so that the last `];` is part of the script block and not trailing off into the normal text

Comment: Click on the link `edited x hours ago` over my name and icon and you should see a side by side difference displayed

Comment: Excellent. I wasn't aware of that feature. Thank you for the edit. Thankfully, I think I have a resolution, about which more soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that we discovered that the library in question is hard wired to the intrinsic PHP Session object, which seems to be constrained to using the filesystem as its backing store. We have since abandoned that library, and are well on our way to implementing Stephen Maguire's dedicated Salesforce provider for The PHP League's OAuth2 library.

Comment: Maguire's library is now fully functional.